# Don't allow direct access to files in a certain subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've tried so many different things in my .htaccess folder and I'm at wits and trying to get this to work.

I have a subdirectory in which contains an .htaccess file. I'd like the files (images, css, js, and the like) in this folder not to be accessed directly. However they need to be accessed/linked to only on the site at www.domain.com/foo/page-name

I've tried the following (not all at once, but separately):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com/foo/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|mp4|mov|js)$ http://domain.com/ [NC]

Redirect 301 /topsecret http://www.domain.com/
```

Does my issue have to do with the .htaccess file being in a subdirectory? This is the only directory I need to limit access to, so I don't see a reason to put it in the root. My knowledge of .htaccess is pretty limited.
I know HTTP REFERER is unsecure but it seems like the best option if I can get it to work.

Comment: The rewrite rules look fine, what doesn't work about it? You're sure the htaccess file is being read and mod_rewrite is turned on?

Comment: @JonLin  The file is being read. If I do something like the RewriteCond, it redirects the direct file when I take off the /foo directory in the referer but it also doesn't allow it to be accessed on www.domain.com/foo/page where I need it to be. It's either full access or no access.